# thymeleaf multiple selected on edit

Tags: thymeleaf, edit, selected

I am totally changing this question, as part of it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606627/spring-mvc-conversion-how-to) with great help of Avnish!
Tom sent me to the right direction so thank you Tom!

My problem is that I do not know how to tell Thymeleaf to preselect object elements when editing it.

Let me show you:

[image: looks like this]

This solution works:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="parts" name="parts" multiple="multiple">
    <option th:each="part : ${partsAtribute}"
            th:selected="${servisAttribute.parts.contains(part)}"
            th:value="${part.id}"
            th:text="${part.name}">Part name</option>
</select>
```

I have tried this:

```html
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{parts}" multiple="multiple">
    <option th:each="part : ${partsAtribute}"
            th:field="*{parts}"
            th:value="${part.id}"
            th:text="${part.name}">Part name</option>
</select>
```

did not work. I also tried this:

```html
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{{parts}}" multiple="multiple">
    <option th:each="part : ${partsAtribute}"
            th:field="*{parts}"
            th:value="${part.id}"
            th:text="${part.name}">Part name</option>
</select>
```

did not work either. I have tried removing `th:field="*{parts}"` from the option tag, same result..

If I change `th:value` to `${part}` it works, but then it does not send back string of ids like [2,4,5,6,...], but `Part` instances like [Part@43b45j, Part@we43y7,...]...

**UPDATE**: I just noticed that this works if only one part is selected:

```html
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{parts}" multiple="multiple">
    <option th:each="part : ${partsAtribute}"
            th:field="*{parts}"
            th:value="${part.id}"
            th:text="${part.name}">Part name</option>
</select>
```

If multiple parts are selected, it does not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After discussion on the Thymeleaf forum, I implemented a full working example at
    https://github.com/jmiguelsamper/thymeleafexamples-selectmultiple

I think that the only problem with your final code is that you have to use double bracket syntax to invoke the conversionService:

```
th:value="${{part}}"
```

It is also important to implement proper equals() and hashcode() methods in your Part class to assure proper comparison.

I hope my example helps other users with similar problems in the future.

Comment: this is a must: "It is also important to implement proper equals() and hashcode() methods in your Part class to assure proper comparison."

Answer (score 10):

You don't need `th:selected` when using `th:field` normally. Thymeleaf will automatically check the values of each `<option>` in the `<select>`, even if it is `multiple`

The problem lies in the value. You are iterating over `parts`, but the value of each option is `part.id`. Thus you are comparing instances of part to the id of part (as far as I can see).

However, Thymeleaf also takes into account instances of `PropertyEditor` (it reuses `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectedValueComparator`).

This will be used when comparing the objects to the values of the options. It will convert the objects to their text value (their id) and compare this to the value.

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{parts}" multiple="multiple" >
        <option th:each="part : ${partsAttribute}" 
                <!-- 
                    Enable the SpringOptionFieldAttrProcessor .
                    th:field value of option must be equal to that of the select tag
                -->
                th:field="*{parts}" 
                th:value="${part.id}" 
                th:text="${part.name} + ${part.serial}">Part name and serial No.                    
        </option>
</select>
```

**Property Editor**

Define a `PropertyEditor` for the parts. The PropertyEditor will be called when comparing the values, and when binding the parts back to the form.

```
@Controller
public class PartsController {
    @Autowired
    private VehicleService vehicleService;

    @InitBinder(value="parts")
    protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Part.class, new PartPropertyEditor ());
    }

    private static class PartPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String partId) {
            final Part part = ...; // Get part based on the id 
            setValue(part);
        }

        /**
         * This is called when checking if an option is selected
         */
        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
           return ((Part)getValue()).getId(); // don't forget null checking
        }
    }
}
```

Also take a look at `ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter`. `Converter` instances that are registered in the `conversionService` are more preferred in Spring nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I have made adjustments and implemented your suggestion, and of course it still does not work. I do not get any errors or anything, just... Can you tell me where to look for examples or documentation on converters, all I found is Spring API... Just so I can understand how this custom custom editor does what it is supposed to do...

Comment: I implemented converter finally. It took some time but it works. Thank you for this. I tried with custom property editor and it works fine as well. I just can't get thymeleaf to work. I will edit my question so you and others can see...

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

A vet has many specialties.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vets/{vetId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editVet(@PathVariable("vetId") int ownerId/*, Model model*/) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("vets/vetEdit");

    mav.addObject("vet", this.vets.findById(ownerId));

    mav.addObject("allSpecialties", this.specialities.findAll());         

    return mav;     
}
```

View (using th:selected):

```
<select id="specialities" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option th:each="s : ${allSpecialties}"                                        
                    th:value="${s.id}"
                    th:text="${s.name}"
                    th:selected="${vet.specialties.contains(s)}">
            </option>
        </select>
```

View (using th:field):

```
<form th:object="${vet}" class="form-horizontal" id="add-vet-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <select th:field="*{specialties}" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option th:each="s : ${allSpecialties}"                                        
                    th:value="${s.id}"
                    th:text="${s.name}"
                   >               
            </option>
        </select>        
    </div>
```

And I have to define `Specialty findOne(@Param("id") Integer id) throws DataAccessException;` in the SpecialtyRepository, otherwise the following exception is thrown : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Repository doesn't have a find-one-method declared!"

```
package org.springframework.samples.petclinic.vet;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface SpecialtyRepository extends Repository<Specialty, Integer> {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)   
    Collection<Specialty> findAll() throws DataAccessException;

    Specialty findOne(@Param("id") Integer id) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much) You saved me!  This worked for me too:  looping  th:each="author : ${authors}"  and selection  th:selected="${task.userList.contains(author)}"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
  <select  th:field="*{influenceIds}" ID="txtCategoryName" class="m-wrap large" multiple="multiple">
    <option th:each="influence : ${influences}" th:value="${influence.get('id')}" th:text="${influence.get('influence')}" ></option>
 </select>
```

My DTO contains:

```
private List<String> influenceIds;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="produtos" name="selectedItens" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple" required="">
                <option th:value="${p.id}" th:text="${p}" th:each="p : ${slideShowForm.itens}" th:selected="${#lists.contains(slideShowForm.selectedItens,p)}"></option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select  th:field="*{groupId}" >
    <option th:each="group :${grouptype}"
            th:value="${{group.groupId}}"
            th:text="${group.Desc}">

    </option>
</select>
```

Simple select example